# Wpf app with AvalonDock docking layout system

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I am creating a small wpf program in .net5. It should have a tab system and a sidebar. The Dirkster.AvalonDock library [github](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock) is suitable for my purposes. Installed version 4.60.0. I just started getting to know this library. The difficulty arose with the sidebar. LayoutAnchorablePane is responsible for its output. But the result is not what I expect.
I need to get something like this
[img1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReydanProjects/DemoApp/master/images/1.png)
There is now
[img2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReydanProjects/DemoApp/master/images/2.png)
View code:

```
    <Window x:Class="TestApp.Views.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cm="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Width="800" Height="450"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" Grid.Column="0"
                DocumentsSource="{Binding Items}"
                AnchorablesSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                >
        <DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cm:View.Model="{Binding Content}" IsTabStop="False" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type LayoutItem}">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
            </Style>
        </DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <LayoutRoot>
            <LayoutPanel>
                <LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <LayoutDocumentPane />
                </LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                    <LayoutAnchorablePane DockMinWidth="300" />
                </LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
            </LayoutPanel>
        </LayoutRoot>
    </DockingManager>
</Grid>
```

The viewmodel code is not important, I think. Also installed in the project is caliburn.micro
Please tell me how to get the sidebar as in the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install VS2013 theme package ([link](http://nuget.org/packages/Dirkster.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2013)) then use the light version like the following:

```xml
<DockingManager.Theme> 
    <Vs2013LightTheme /> 
</DockingManager.Theme>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to get. I did not think that the styles of influence on the display of buttons in the sidebar.

Comment: No, the theme does affect the look only. However, the absence of buttons (and the whole header) in your case seem to be a bug in latest version (4.6), see this [issue](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/issues/309)